# Inflection point and 2nd derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Is it possible a function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to have an inflection point somewhere but that it is not two times differentiable at that point?

If so, then can we have a form of that function? Can we construct one?

Comment: $f(x)=x\cdot|x|$.

Comment: Inflection points are defined at points where the second derivative changes from positive to negative or negative to positive. Therefore, if we had a function where $f''(x) = \frac{1}{x - 1}$, it obivously isn't defined for $x = 1$. However, since the second derivative changes signs at this point, it can be called an inflection point.